# reordering personal ids between columns

Tags: r

Consider the following (smalle subsample) of a dataset of same-sex couples.

```
df<-data.frame(c("A1", "A2"), c("q2", "q3"), c("q1","q4"), c(19520410, 19510101), c(19500702, 19651215))
colnames(df)<-c("householdnr", "id_1", "id_2", "birthday_1", "birthday_2")
```

In the above dataset, the householdnr indicates which persons belong to each other whereas the id_1 and id_2 column specify which person is in a particular couple.

Now the problem is that I want the people with the earliest birthdate of the two persons in a couple in the id_1 column (This makes my analysis later on much easier to determine when I have to divide the oldest person into subgroups). In other words I would like to get my output like this.

```
householdnr  id_1 id_2  birthday_1 birthday_2
A1            q1   q2   1950-07-02  1952-04-10
A2            q3   q4   1951-01-01  1965-12-15
```

Does anyone have any idea how I should do this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first get the data in long format by separating birthdays and id value in different columns, `arrange` the data by `birthday` and get the data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -householdnr, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'value'), 
               names_sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(birthday = lubridate::ymd(birthday)) %>%
  arrange(householdnr, birthday) %>%
  group_by(householdnr) %>%
  mutate(value = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = c(id, birthday))

#  householdnr id_1  id_2  birthday_1 birthday_2
#  <chr>       <chr> <chr> <date>     <date>    
#1 A1          q1    q2    1950-07-02 1952-04-10
#2 A2          q3    q4    1951-01-01 1965-12-15
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty, base R solution, useful if your dataset is not very large as it involves a `for` cycle.

First, I convert the factors as characters, and I create proper date variables using the `lubridate` package

```
df$id_1 <- as.character(df$id_1)
df$id_2 <- as.character(df$id_2)
df$birthday_1 <- lubridate::ymd(df$birthday_1)
df$birthday_2 <- lubridate::ymd(df$birthday_2)
```

Then, use the `for` cycle

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
  if(df$birthday_1[i] > df$birthday_2[i]){

    # invert IDs
    temp <- df$id_1[i]
    df$id_1[i] <- df$id_2[i]
    df$id_2[i] <- temp

    # invert dates
    temp <- df$birthday_1[i]
    df$birthday_1[i] <- df$birthday_2[i]
    df$birthday_2[i] <- temp
  }
```

Output

```
  householdnr id_1 id_2 birthday_1 birthday_2
1          A1   q1   q2 1950-07-02 1952-04-10
2          A2   q3   q4 1951-01-01 1965-12-15
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried something similar but my dataset was apperently to big to use this loop. But for smaller datasets your solution indeed works.